# How to create a proper time series `ts()` object with weekly figures in R

Tags: r, time-series

I often used the `ts()` objects for yearly, quarterly or monthly time series, but now I would like to use it for weekly. Now the challenge is that not every year has the same number of weeks (either 52 or 53 weeks). How to deal with this?

I usually take the first day of the week as an identifier for the week (e.g. 2013-05-20 or 2013-05-27).

Can anybody advise how I would create a proper weekly time serie for the following dataset (x).

```
Date            Qty
2013-05-20      25
2013-05-27      60
....
```

Something along the lines of:

```
ts <- ts(x$Qty, start=as.Date(x$Date), frequency=????)
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: There is no solution for this problem as far as I know. I'm also dealing with weekly sales data on a regular basis which is really hard to work with in R. Especially when wanting to use stl etc. for seasonality and trend detection.

Answer (score 2):

```
DF <- read.table(text="Date            Qty
2013-05-20      25
2013-05-27      60",header=TRUE)

DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date)

library(xts)
my.xts <- as.xts(DF[,-1,drop=FALSE],order.by=DF$Date)
as.ts(my.xts)
# Time Series:
# Start = 1 
# End = 8 
# Frequency = 0.142857142857143 
# [1] 25 60
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you cannot work with this kind of time series when decomposing into seasonality and trend for example. Working with weekly data is a major problem everywhere since the frequency is not constant over time. Some years have 53 weeks and some have 52. 2009 in Europe is an example of a year with 53 weeks.

Comment: I think this comment should be below the question and not my answer.

Comment: I put it under your answer since I don't think your answer solves the problem mentioned: "Can anybody advise how I would create a proper weekly time series". Your answer coerces the data into a ts structure that is not a "proper weekly time series" in my opinion.

Comment: It's the responsibility of the question to define the desired result. "proper"  is quite subjective.

Comment: I agree that the question should have specified in more detail what is meant by proper. However, I guess you can agree with me that a frequency of 0.1428 is nonsense when dealing with weekly data?